# Program that creates a child process, sends it a text and returns it in uppercase, using bufferReader

Tags: java

**I am trying to send a string to the child and print it from the parent, but i always get a "null".Is the correct way to read the string of the child?
Perhaps it is better to do it with Scanner?
I've never done it with "Parent/Child", I've always done it with sockets and I'm a bit lost
Thanks**

Parent

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Padre {

public static void main(String args[]) {
String line;

try {

Process hijo = new ProcessBuilder("java","Hijo").start();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hijo.getInputStream()));
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(hijo.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System. in));

System.out.println("Enviar un mensaje al proceso hijo:");
line = in.readLine();
ps.println(line);
line = br.readLine();
System.out.println(line) ;

 } catch (IOException e) {
 System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
 }

}
}
```

Child

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Hijo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String leer;

    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        leer = br.readLine().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(leer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes everything works properly and might be missing an error in the sub-process. Change the launch to redirect stderr -> stdout and it should give back more details:

```
 Process hijo = new ProcessBuilder("java","Hijo").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
```

or put errors to a file to read later.

```
 Process hijo = new ProcessBuilder("java","Hijo").redirectError(new File("stderr.log")).start();
```

The command you use might also need extra details for path to current directory or setting classpath, something like:

```
 Process hijo = new ProcessBuilder(
       System.getProperty("java.home")+"/bin/java",
       "-cp", System.getProperty("java.class.path")
       ,"Hijo")
```